# MySQL how to get the total sum of a column one to one table using CMD

Tags: mysql, syntax

I'm doing a code for MySQL that can get all of the sum of one column except for  the distinct value. So here is the picture. There are two tables that have to join in-order to get the sum of 2050, what'd be the syntax to get that sum?

[image]

Comment: please update you question with the text and don't use image only ..  normally the who answer don't like write your text ..

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't explain it clearly if I don't use picture.. 
I'm sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need  the sum for west

```
 Select sum(sales)
 from store_information
 LEFT JOIN geography on geography.store_name = store_information.store_name 
 where region = 'West'
```

Comment: @IostreamDoTeych  Next time add  text too .. so the answers  don't have to do all the job  ..

Comment: Noted, I'm sorry I just can't clearly explain.. Btw. Thankyou for answering my question..

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select region,sum(sales)
  from store_information,geography
  Group by region
```

Will give sales by geography.
Now you can select required geography and saleAmount

Comment: uhmm, I only need to get a sum of 2050 only one field for the output..
Output would be Sum(Sales) = 2050.